# Will IntelliJ IDEA work on Mac with ARM processor (Apple Silicone)

Tags: intellij-idea

Will IntelliJ IDEA work flawlessly with the new Apple processor?

Because I read some blog that, they said some barrier in with third party software with new ARM processor on Mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will work on the Apple Silicone. Please [follow this task for updates](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2526).

Current Status: JetBrains is working on porting JetBrains Runtime (and all products running on JVM) to Apple Silicon. We’re waiting for a Developer Transition Kit (DTK) box to test our IDEs. We aim to make our products work on the new Apple processors starting from the day of the official hardware availability for purchase. Watch the ticket for updates.